# Android Navigation Graph, Nested Graph Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I hope you're all doing well.

I have a problem about navigation graphs.  You can see the structure in the image below;

[image]
So we have 2 different navigation graphs; `navigation_A` and `navigation_B`.

I need to navigate to `Fragment Y` and `Fragment Z` from a fragment in nested graph which is `navigation_B`.

The problem is;

- If I use `<include>` for `navigation_B`, I can not use it as `NavHost`.
- If I use different navigation graph and add it as nested graph like above, I can not use navigation destination for `Fragment Y` or `Fragment Z`.

I need to use `navigation_B` as `NavHost`, also i need to be able to navigate to `Fragment Y` and `Fragment Z`. How can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your navigation graph structure breaks the recommended navigation pattern!

But for your needs, I have a way to workaround.

Method 1:
First, FragmentY and FragmentZ need to have their own deeplinks.

```xml
    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/fragY"
      android:name=".FragmentY"
      tools:layout="@layout/frag_y">
      <deepLink
        android:id="@+id/"
        app:uri="any-app://internal_navigation_frag_y" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/fragZ"
      android:name=".FragmentZ"
      tools:layout="@layout/frag_z">
      <deepLink
        android:id="@+id/dlink_frag_z"
        app:uri="any-app://internal_navigation_frag_z" />
    </fragment>
```

Then, Inside a Fragment that lives in navigation_b. Let's call it FragmentB

```
// navigate to FramgmentY
val deeplinkY = Uri.parse("any-app://internal_navigation_frag_y")
findNavController().navigate(deeplinkY)

// navigate to FramgmentZ
val deeplinkZ = Uri.parse("any-app://internal_navigation_frag_z")
findNavController().navigate(deeplinkZ)
```

You can store the string `any-app://internal_navigation_frag_y` and `any-app://internal_navigation_frag_z` in string.xml file though.

Check this out: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#uri

Method 2:
Inside the nested graph navigation_B, define 2 global actions that point to fragmentY and fragmentZ. Since navigation_B is a NavHost, so it will know about FragmentY and FragmnentZ

Check this: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action

Comment: Thanks a lot. The deeplink option helped.
Can this work with multi-modular applications too @Hau Luu

Comment: @DenisOluka, haven't tested multi-modular yet. But theoretically, It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

When you use nested navigation graph the inner graph should not know anything about the outside graph. In this case graph_B should not know about the existence of a FragmentY or FragmentZ. What you should do is deliver a result from your graph_B to whomever launched it. Then at that point decide whether to go FragmentY or FragmentZ.